# GridSearchCV uses predict or predict_proba?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

It works for the *huber* and *log*, however only the logarithm has a predict_proba? How it works? I used *roc_auc_score*.

Answer (score 1):

as it has written in O'reily book it works on `mean_score` as you can access to all mean_scores it got with this code

```
 cvres = grid_search.cv_results_
 for mean_score, params in zip(cvres["mean_test_score"], cvres["params"]):
   print(np.sqrt(-mean_score), params)
```

it will print all mean_scores that calculated for each param and you can see the difference between them easily

Answer (score 1):

Grid Search CV has both the predict and the predict_proba functions.

If you consider a binary classification problem, predict will have the values of 0 or 1. While, Predict_proba will have the probability values of it being 0 or 1.
predict_proba will have an array output like [0.23 0.77]